# Camshaft sensor reading

Tags: ford, explorer, cam-position-sensor

I have a 2002 Ford Explorer XLT 2WD 4.0 6 cylinder Gas

I don't know how much of that matters for a camshaft sensor, but for some reason I got urge today to test my camshaft sensor, when I did I got an ohms reading of .756

I don't know if the ohms reading is different for every car and truck, or if it's generally the same. Personally I think it's low because I seen a video saying a good reading for a camshaft sensor is 2.0 ohms (2000) and my vehicle has had a misfire for awhile and the mileage reading will jump from from trip to total mileage driven randomly

Comment: is this a 4l sohc or ohv?

Comment: I believe it's an ohv but don't hold me to that

Answer (score 1):

If the camshaft position sensor (CPS) is a Hall sensor, it works by translating changes in magnetic field to changes in voltage via inductance.

Such sensors can degrade with time (and use) through demagnetization; measuring its internal resistance will not indicate this type of degradation.

Comment: So how are their magnetic fields tested

Comment: That's a good question which should be asked separately.

Comment: If you want to get into the weeds with it and use an oscilloscope, that's your prerogative - But the dealer will have a computer to gather more insightful data.